# windows form get image from url, using json

Tags: c#, json, winforms, openweathermap

i have problems for get the imagen from the json, i try to make a api using json and c# to show weather for some city but i can´t print the image the result is 0, no error but dont show nothing. i using too newtonsoft for json. i dont have problems for get other parameters like wind or timezone. but i have problems for get the image for the json, what am I doing wrong, please some help or example

this is my main class

```
   void getweather()
        {
            using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
            {
                string url = string.Format("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=-42.15&lon=-12.9167&appid=4ef889ce24xxxxxx4b&units=metric&cnt=6");
                var json = web.DownloadString(url);
                // var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherInfo.root>(json);
                //    WeatherInfo.root outPut = result;
                WeatherInfo.Root Info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherInfo.Root>(json);
                STRGRADOS.Text = string.Format("{0} \u00B0" + "C", Info.main.temp);
                pic_icon.ImageLocation = "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + Info.weather[0].icon+".PNG";
                HUMEDAD.Text = string.Format("{0}", Info.main.humidity + "%");
                Console.WriteLine(Info);
            }
        }
```

this is my class for get the info

```
class WeatherInfo{

 public class Weather
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string main { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string icon { get; set; }
        }

   public class Root
        {
            public Coord coord { get; set; }
            public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
            public string @base { get; set; }
            public Main main { get; set; }
            public int visibility { get; set; }
            public Wind wind { get; set; }
            public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
            public int dt { get; set; }
            public Sys sys { get; set; }
            public int timezone { get; set; }
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int cod { get; set; }
        }
}
```

i test with this json

```
{"coord":{"lon":-32.9167,"lat":-12.15},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":25.26,"feels_like":25.64,"temp_min":25.26,"temp_max":25.26,"pressure":1018,"humidity":69,"sea_level":1018,"grnd_level":1018},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":7.82,"deg":166,"gust":7.68},"clouds":{"all":79},"dt":1688501669,"sys":{"sunrise":1688459581,"sunset":1688500721},"timezone":-7200,"id":0,"name":"","cod":200}
```

Comment: 1. What is the type of the `pic_icon`? 2. I tried to build the URL of the icon by your code and json provided and got `https://openweathermap.org/img/w/04n.PNG`. And this URL gives me `404 not found` error. Can you please double check the URL generation?

Comment: is png with lowercase my bad sorry but i change that and nothing happens, the url showme a img, but not generate in the form

Comment: Ok, got it for the url. And what about the type of the `pic_icon`?

Comment: its a picturebox

Comment: I just checked your code (deserialising from json string + building the url (with PNG->png fix) + setting that url in the `PictrueBox`. And I can see the image on my form. Can you please provide a minimal reproducible sample that demonstrates the problem? Ideally, the sample should get json from string and do not download it from the remote API.

Comment: i resolve the problem with this line      pic_icon.ImageLocation = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + Info.weather[0].icon + ".png"; i think the reason is the "s" in the https, thanks